# React progects not working in windows 10?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, import, export

I am working in MacBook Pro in React. The project works well. But I am running this project on Windows 10 and it drops a lot of errors. Switching property allowSyntheticDefaultImports in true
does not lead to success. An error: 'An export assignment cannot be used in a module with other exported elements.'
TSconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "build",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2019.object", "es2016.array.include"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "./src/",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports" : false,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "typescript-tslint-plugin",
      }
    ],
    "baseUrl": "./src/",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "cache",
    "build",
    "scripts",
    "cypress",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack",
    "jest",
    "config",
    "src/setupTests.ts"
  ]
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> try adding "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true in compilerOptions in
> your tsconfig.json file and then use the syntax

Or try setting the esModuleInterop flag to true.

> With flag esModuleInterop we can import CommonJS modules in compliance
> with es6 modules spec
> your file will look like this.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "build",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "es2019.object", "es2016.array.include"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "./src/",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports" : false,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "typescript-tslint-plugin",
      }
    ],
    "baseUrl": "./src/",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "cache",
    "build",
    "scripts",
    "cypress",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack",
    "jest",
    "config",
    "src/setupTests.ts"
  ],

"esModuleInterop": true, //<----------------------------add this
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true //<----------------------------and this
}
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't help (((